# how to implement "contains" function in Mysql4.x?

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a keywords table,and i want to check a String contains keyword or not.

```
String str="aaabbbccc";

TableName:keywordTable
field:id keyword
-------------------
1 ee
2 bbb
3 xx
..
------------------
```

i run this sql (in mysql 4.1):

```
select * from `keywordTable` where contains(`keyword`,"aaabbbccc");
```

return a syntax error

how to implement it? (in mysql 4.1 and 4.0)

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from `keywordtable`
where  'aaabbbcccc' like CONCAT('%',`keyword`,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from `keywordtable`
where `keyword` like '%aaabbbcccc%'
```

the only problem is, that it searches case-insensitive, so AAAAAABBBCCCCCCCCDDD will also be matched

edit. i misread, you want to match the other way round. do this instead:

```
select *
from `keywordtable`
where 'aaabbbcccc' like '%'+`keyword`+'%'
```

mysql also understands `like` in reversed order

Comment: keyword=='aa'
string =='aaabbbccc'

select * 
from `keywordtable` 
where `keyword` like '%aaabbbccc%' ? i think this not right.